# Can Storyboard execute a custom function?

Tags: c#, wpf

The common use of `Storyboard` is to execute multiple animations at different `BeginTime`, i.e.:

```
Storyboard m_storyboard = new Storyboard();

var fadeInAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(1d, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
fadeInAnimation.BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
Storyboard.SetTarget(fadeInAnimation, grid);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(fadeInAnimation, new PropertyPath(Grid.OpacityProperty));
m_storyboard.Children.Add(fadeInAnimation);

var fadeOutAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(1d, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
fadeOutAnimation.BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
Storyboard.SetTarget(fadeOutAnimation, label);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(fadeOutAnimation, new PropertyPath(Label.OpacityProperty));
m_storyboard.Children.Add(fadeOutAnimation);

m_storyboard.Begin();
```

But I would like to set up the `Storyboard` so it can call my custom function at a specified `BeginTime` - is it possible?

```
public void CustomFunction()
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: You may want to take a look at [Custom Animations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970564(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: As far as I understand from the docs the suggested approaches are all related to animated something. Instead, I'm looking for a "one-shot" call to a function when the elapsed time of the `Storyboard` reaches the specified `BeginTime`.